# Export OWC11.axSpreadsheet to Excel file in VB.net Visual Studio 2013

Tags: excel, visual-studio-2013

I am using a spreadsheet control (Microsoft OWC.axSpreadsheet) in Visual Studio 2013.  I am wondering if there is a way to export the contents to an Excel spreadsheet.  The control supports an Export function.  I am just not sure the proper syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Looking around, I found the answer.  This code will export the contents of the owc control to a spreadsheet file:

Positions.Export("c:\testexport.xls", Microsoft.Office.Interop.Owc11.SheetExportActionEnum.ssExportActionNone, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Owc11.SheetExportFormat.ssExportXMLSpreadsheet)